# Elasticsearch How to do function score query with prefix PLUS fuzzyness

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do `phrase_prefix` and `fuzziness` query on same data.

Here is what i came up with, It is not working:

```
{
    from: 0,
    size: 10,
    query: {
        function_score: {
            query: { "match_all": {} },
            boost: "5",
            functions: [{
                filter: {
                    multi_match: {
                        query: query,
                        type: 'phrase_prefix',
                        fields: ['text', 'fullText']
                    }
                }
            }, {
                filter: {
                    multi_match: {
                        query: query,
                        fuzziness: "AUTO",
                        fields: ['text', 'fullText']
                    }
                }
            }],
            query: {},
            field_value_factor: {
                field: 'score',
                factor: 1.2,
                missing: 1
            }
        }
    },
    filter: {
        term: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

It is clear that i do not understand elasticsearch queries yet, can someone help me out

Comment: need to see mappings and schema and also i need to understand what you want to search  and how you want to boost the terms in the search.

Comment: Just tell me in a general case how would you do a `function_score` query with two `multi_match`, 1. with `phrase_prefix` and 2. with `fuzzyness`. Terms are boosted with field with score which is some number (based on popularity of that text).